# How do I create bidirectional entity references?

Tags: entities

How can I create a bidirectional link in a drupal entity? Let me explain, I have a content type called "software" in which I have a field (entity reference) called "article". When I create my "software" content, Drupal automatically creates a link to my "article" content type, which is fine, but I would like a link to be created in the opposite direction from my "article" content type to my "software" content type. How can I do this?

Comment: The question is why you need a different database schema. It doesn't seem to be necessary for creating a link in the opposite direction. This is possible by querying the "article" id in the reference field of the "software" content type.

Comment: Thank you for the answer Cilefen, I followed the link but unfortunately the Entity Reference module that is specified is only usable for Drupal 7 and I work with Drupal 9. I saw that there was also a cnr module, but the problem is the same to make it work I need another module that works only in Drupal 7.

Comment: Nevertheless this question is the same question.

Comment: Thank you Cilefen, after having deepened the subject a little I finally found thanks to the cnr module. Your answer is correct.